# Does anyone know how I can directly use classes under sun.awt namespace in a JBOSS 7.1 servelet?

Tags: jboss, noclassdeffounderror

We have a customer who create a servelet to be hosted in JBOSS 7.1 on Windows 7 64-bit and the servelet uses the java classes in a jar file we develop. One of our classes makes use of sun.awt.DisplayChangedListener interface. The problem is that we get NoClassDefFoundError exception from the class that uses the DisplayChangedListener when the servelet is called and DisplayChangedListener is the root cause. There is no problem with many other classes in the same rt.jar file where DisplayChangedListener also resides. I use process explorer to look at the jar files the JBOSS process loads and only one rt.jar file is there. If I run the same codes directly using java, I have no problem. If I place a copy of rt.jar file to the local repository of the deployed servelet application in JBOSS, there is no problem as well. I know classes under sun.awt namespace are supposed to use internally not by developers, and it seems like the JBOSS class loader reinforece the restriction on their use. Is there any way I can make it work without the local copy of rt.jar and without abandoning the use of DisplayChangedListener interface (such as through some setting in configuration files)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Never mind the use of `sun.*`, why are you using AWT classes in a webapp at all?

Comment: Can you explain why your customer uses AWT in a servlet, moreover why they use restricted and unofficial AWT API?

Comment: I know we shouldn't have used any class from sun.awt.* directly. The problem is that the library that uses the class from sun.awt.* has been shipped to our customers for almost 2 years and I try to see if there is a way to workaround this for the customers who don't want to wait/upgrade to the next release.

Answer (score 0):

The steps I recommend are:

1. create a new module
2. add the following dependany (with edits for the packages you need)

```
    ...
       <dependencies>
       <system export="true">
         <paths> 
           <path name="com/sun"/> 
           <path name="com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl"/> 
         </paths> 
       </system> 
       <module name="javax.api"/> 
       <module name="org.apache.log4j"/> 
       <module name="sun.jdk" export="true"/> 
     </dependencies>
```

1. make your application depend on the module.